# How to implement a soft-delete feature?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, soft-delete

Currently I am fetching specific data from my DB to display it above a form. The form is there for adding another dataset to the DB. So every time a dataset is added, it should be displayed above the form. It should also be possible to soft-delete it. I got a tinyint field in my DB - "soft_deleted". That should go to 1 if a button next to the fetched dataset is clicked. Also the displayed data should disappear. I am posting my current code here, already got the disappearing of the data working but I have no clue how to update my dataset so soft_deleted goes to 1 if the button is clicked.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('div').on('click', '#soft_delete_button_' . $person_id, function () {
                    $(this).closest('div').remove();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM personen WHERE ... AND soft_deleted = 0";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($resultCheck > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

            $person_id = $row['person_id'];
            echo "<div id='" . $row['person_id'] . "'>" . "<button type='button' id='soft_delete_button_" . $person_id . "' name='soft_delete_button_" . $person_id . "'>X</button> " . $row['name'],", ", $row['vorname'] . "</div>";

        }
    }

    ?>
    <form action="haushaltsmitglieder_action.php" method="post">
    .
    .
    .
```

I am open to other solutions as well. Doesn't have to be the button. My aim is to be able to soft-delete the displayed data per one-click.

Comment: You could make your code send and AJAX request to the server when the button is clicked, and send the ID of the record to be deleted. That would then run an UPDATE query in the database to set the soft_deleted field to 1 for that record.

Comment: @ADyson this seems so easy. I tried different ideas now for hours and also can't find a single example how to actually update data to mysql. The web is just flooded with "How to fetch and display data via Ajax". Do you maybe have an example or some well-explaining website for that matter? Notice, I am pretty new to coding.

Comment: Break it down into parts. Making an AJAX request is making an AJAX request...you send a request to the server, you get a response back. You can send data, or you can receive data, or both, doesn't really matter. So learn how to do that and send the ID, first of all. What the PHP script does when it receives the AJAX request is entirely its business. If you learn how to write an UPDATE query and put the received ID into it as a parameter, then you'll have done the next part of the job. The smaller parts you break down the task into, the easier they are to research and implement individually.

Comment: I'll give it a go and learn more about AJAX - step by step, as you say. I think I have a lot to learn. Thank you very much for the support already! I will return to report my progress.

Comment: I finally made it working. I used custom attributes (data-event-type and data-person-id) to give to my buttons (value of the associated ID) and tranferred these values via ajax to my test.php where I've done the SQL UPDATE statement. Now every time I click the dynamically generated button the associated data gets updated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually it can be done by taking a `deleted` field who's type is a timestamp and default NULL and to query the db you'll ask for all the records whose deleted field is NULL.

This way you can also check what is deleted and when.

Now on click of the button you can send ajax request (you can also check `fetch` or `axios` for that matter) to an endpoint which in turn save the current timestamp in the deleted field.

Below is an fetch example which you can try:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id', '1');

fetch('htt://localhost:3000/delete', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {
  console.log('Success:', result);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

Comment: Apart from the _timestamp_ aspect, how is that significantly different from what the OP is already doing? The **actual** question they're asking is *"I have no clue how to update my dataset so soft_deleted goes to 1 if the button is clicked."*